# How to get chat_id, user_id and time from telegram bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

I am writing a telegram bot to handle conversations (one to one) with users and I am getting same for both userid and chat_id.

My code is:

```
chat_id = update.message.chat_id
user_id = update.effective_user.id
```

Comment: I think in one-on-one conversations these are the same. They have different values in a group chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user_id` is the Telegram ID of the user sending a message to bot.
`chat_id` is the Telegram ID of the chat where a message is being sent to bot.

So, in one to one conversation, the user will send a message in his own chat (with respect to bot). That's the reason both are same.

Comment: so user_id is unique to every user and it doesn't change?

Comment: @Shubh Yes, `user_id` will never change and it's unique for every Telegram user. Same applies to Groups and Channels, `chat_id` in this case.